# Cygwin 'cd' command always tells me "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, path, cygwin, cd

When i login to the cygwin terminal and type:

```
cd "cygdrive/c/existing/path"
```

it tells me, "no such file or directory". i am sure the path exists... do i miss a special cygwin package, or do i have a false configuration? i am puzzled...

It behaves the same when i try to call the cygwin bash from a windows batch file.
what i basically want to do is creating a windows batch file which starts cygwin and executes a shell script with a specified working directory as its described in this blog post: http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/01/27/executing-cygwin-bash-scripts-on-windows/

my batch file seems to work, it does the following command:

```
%_CYGBIN%\bash.exe --login "cd %_CYGPATH%" "./%_CYGSCRIPT%"
```

but cygwin won't execute the 'cd' command. The console output of my batch file is:

```
/usr/bin/bash: cd /cygdrive/c/existing/path: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```sh
cd '/cygdrive/c/existing/path'
#   ^
#    \
#     --- need forward slash (/) before the "c"
```